# PCI Passthrough - Code 12 on Windows 7 Guest

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, graphics-card, linux-mint, pci

I've gotten fairly far in setting this up, but I'm left with both the Video and Audio devices in my GTX 1070 unable to load because of this error `This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)`

Specs:
 - i7-5820K (OC'd to 3.8GHz)
 - MSI x99 SLI Krait Edition
 - Passing: GTX 1070 (Founder's)
 - Host: Linux Mint 18.1 x64
 - Guest: Windows 7 Ultimate x64
 - Using Virtual Box

Comment: Did you ever find answer?